# Converting a stateful component to stateless

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stateless, stateful

i'm pretty new to react and redux and i'm having an issue here. It's mandatory to use only stateless components with containers whenever state handing is required. These two components are:

```
import React from 'react';
import DatePicker from '../DatePicker';

class DayInput extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dateValue: new Date(),
      activeDateWidget: false,
    };
  }

  changeDate(date) {
    this.setState({
      dateValue: date,
    });
  }

  changeActiveDateWidget(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.setState({
      activeDateWidget: !this.state.activeDateWidget,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { input, meta } = this.props;
    const { dateValue, activeDateWidget } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          {...input}
          className="form-control"
          type="text"
          value={dateValue}
          onClick={this.changeActiveDateWidget}
          // onBlur={this.changeActiveDateWidget}
        />

        {activeDateWidget ? (
          <div>
            <DatePicker
              changeActiveDateWidget={this.changeActiveDateWidget}
              changeDate={this.changeDate}
              dateValue={dateValue}
            />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default DayInput;

import React from 'react';
import 'react-day-picker/lib/style.css';
import DayPicker, { DateUtils } from 'react-day-picker';

class DatePicker extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedDay: new Date(),
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.input) {
      this.input.focus();
    }
  }

  handleDayClick(e, day, { disabled }) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (disabled) {
      return;
    }
    this.setState({ selectedDay: day }, () => {
      this.props.changeDate(day);
      this.props.changeActiveDateWidget();
    });
  }

  focusThisComponent(e) {
    if (e) {
      this.input = e;
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { changeActiveDateWidget } = this.props;
    const { selectedDay } = this.state;
    return (
      <div
        ref={this.focusThisComponent}
        tabIndex="1"
      >
        <DayPicker
          id="THISTHING"
          initialMonth={selectedDay}
          selectedDays={day => DateUtils.isSameDay(selectedDay, day)}
          onDayClick={this.handleDayClick}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DatePicker;
```

As you can see the first component is wrapped inside the second component. I tried to convert the first component myself like this:

```
const DayInput = props => {
  <input
    {...props.input}
    type="text"
    value= {new Date()}
    onClick={()=>??}
   />
}
```

but as you can see i dont know how to handle the onclick event. Can someone help me to achieve this?

Comment: Will you use redux or the state of the root component ?

Comment: your `DayInput` isn't returning anything

Comment: The state of the root component. i returned from the DayInput by nothing works. Just i didnt include it here

Comment: @DanielLizik is right you must return something in your component (change {<input ...} with (<input ...) ). `(..)` stands for `{ return (..) }`

Comment: The statefull components are working fine, The problem is that i'm having difficulties to convert them into stateless

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something important :P

Comment: @user7334203, I give you an example in 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn your component in a stateless component, you must pass everything as properties of the component.

This will be your DayInput splitted into 2 components :

```
const DayInputShow = props => {
  return (<input
    {...props.input}
    type="text"
    value= {props.value}
    onClick={(event)=>props.onClick()}
    />);
};

const DayInputEdit = props => {
  return (<DatePicker
    changeActiveDateWidget={props.changeActiveDateWidget}
    changeDate={props.onChange}
    dateValue={props.value}
  />);
};

DayInputShow.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.date,
  onClick: PropTypes.func,      
}

DayInputEdit.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.date,
  onChange: PropTypes.func,      
}
```

And this will be the root component (uncomplete and still statefull) :

```
class DatePicker extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedDay: new Date(),
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.input) {
      this.input.focus();
    }
  }

  handleDayClick(e, day, { disabled }) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (disabled) {
      return;
    }
    this.setState({ selectedDay: day }, () => {
      this.props.changeDate(day);
      this.props.changeActiveDateWidget();
    });
  }

  focusThisComponent(e) {
    if (e) {
      this.input = e;
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { changeActiveDateWidget } = this.props;
    const { selectedDay } = this.state;
    let dayPicker;
    if (this.input) {
      dayPicker = <DayPickerEdit
          value={this.state.selectedDay}
          onChange={(value) => {this.setState({selectedDay: value})}}
          selectedDays={day => DateUtils.isSameDay(selectedDay, day)}
          onDayClick={this.handleDayClick}
        />
    } else {
      dayPicker = <DayPickerShow
          value={this.state.selectedDay}
          ref={(input) => { this.inputRef = input; }} />
          onClick={() => {this.focusThisComponent(this.inputRef )}}
        />
    }
    return (
      <div
        ref={this.focusThisComponent}
        tabIndex="1"
      >
        {dayPicker }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DatePicker;
```

Comment: Great mate...but i was wondering...could we transform the root component into stateless?

Comment: Yes, you can but you will need a redux store. You will to store all your state in your store but it will be much convenient to use and read.

Comment: I have to do it this way because it is mandatory for my project not to use stateful components